# Why can't I delete the Ogre OverlaySystem created with new?

Tags: c++, pointers, access-violation, ogre

I am using the Ogre framework for my application. When the application shuts down I shut down Ogre deleting the Ogre::Root object. After that I need to delete some pointers, because I have own classes for every Ogre class I use as interfaces. I just delete the pointers to my classes. The pointers that existed to Ogre elements are not deleted since the Ogre shut down takes care of it (or at least it should according to the documentation).

The problem lies within the OverlaySystem class. This is the header file:

```
class OverlaySystem {
public:
    OverlaySystem();
    Ogre::OverlaySystem* getOverlaySystem() const;
    ~OverlaySystem();

private:
    Ogre::OverlaySystem* overlaySystem;
};
```

and this is the source file:

```
OverlaySystem::OverlaySystem() :
overlaySystem(new Ogre::OverlaySystem()) {
}

Ogre::OverlaySystem* OverlaySystem::getOverlaySystem() const {
    return this->overlaySystem;
}

OverlaySystem::~OverlaySystem() {
    delete this->overlaySystem;
}
```

My understanding is as follows: since I dynamically allocate memory for the Ogre::OverlaySystem object I have to delete the pointer freeing the allocated memory, which is what I do in the destructor (or at least I thought I would).

The problem is: when my application shuts down I get an exception deleting the Ogre::OverlaySystem object because of an access violation saying that I can't read at position 0x00000042. Here is an example of the failure (sorry for german but I can't change that right now):

[image: Access Violation Exception]

The only address changing is the exception address itself, which is the first one.

I spent hours now searching for my failure or the reason for this but I can't find anything helping. It would be really great if someone could help me solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework, but a few ideas: Have you checked that your create method actually returns a valid, non-null pointer? (I guess so, if you only get the error on closing.) Does anything else in your architecture `delete` the pointer or take over ownership of it? Is there a reason you can't use `std::unique_ptr` to manage the instance? Or... are you compiling one version of the object file but `#include`ing a different version of its header elsewhere in your project? The latter has caused me some very confusing issues until I realised how simple a mistake it is.

Comment: To elaborate, if you (e.g. by not syncing all your nested `git` submodules) compile a newer version of `SomeObject.cpp`, but some other source file `#include`s an older version of `SomeObject.hpp`, the object file compiled from that source is at risk of accessing members/vptrs at wrong offsets in `SomeObject`, meaning anything can happen. I've seen crashes instantly, or only on exit; the latter was surprising as it worked fine at runtime but only segfaulted/terminated at exit. Wasn't consistent either - `gdb` showed several different failure modes. That's UB for ya!

Comment: I bet you make a copy somewhere of your `OverlaySystem` objet. When the first object is destroyed it `delete`s the `Ogre::OverlaySystem*` and the second object destruction `delete`s an already-deleted-pointer. Hence the crash. Try to declare a private copy-constructor and assignment-operator in your class.

Comment: @underscore_d failure with `new` either throws an exception or returns `nullptr`. Since the crash happens at program terminaison, the exception scenario can't be considered. If the `new` failed by returning `nullptr`, `delete nullptr` wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @YSC:
The only thing I do with the `Ogre::OverlaySystem` object is adding it as a render queue listener to my `Ogre::SceneManager` using:
`sceneManager->addRenderQueueListener(overlaySystem);`

I couldn't find anything about that, but could that mean, the `Ogre::OverlaySystem` get's destroyed on Ogre shutdown deleting the `Ogre::Root` object? And if so: Why do things like a frame listener not get destroyed on shutdown?

Comment: Surely the documentation will stipulate anywhere that a passed resources has its ownership transferred or is scheduled for deletion?

Comment: @YSC: I added `OverlaySystem(const OverlaySystem&) = delete;` and `OverlaySystem& operator=(const OverlaySystem&) = delete;` to ecplicitly disallow copying but my code compiles and runs fine just until this damn deletion of the `Ogre::OverlaySystem` object.

Comment: My bad. You're up to debug your code to see what's happening. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error! I thought I had done that already but there must habe been some mix up after several changes.

Solution:
The destructor of `Ogre::OverlaySystem` must be called BEFORE the destructor of `Ogre::Root` is called.